# Gson freezing program

Tags: java, android, gson

I am trying to pass an object into an intent and i read a different post on here to use Gson. now it doesn't show any errors and it runs. But when i click a button it just freezes my phone. there is no exception thrown.

```
OnCreate {
...
listViewObjects.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Person item = (Person)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.name + " selected\n" + item.status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(item);
                PersonDescriptionPage.putExtra("person", json);
                startActivity(PersonDescriptionPage);
            }
        });
}
```

i originally had it as one line with an anonymous Gson Object

```
PersonDescriptionPage.putExtra("person", new Gson().toJson(item));
```

and if i debug it it freezes on this line. so I then split it up into an instantiated object that you see in the first block of code above and it freezes on the `gson.toJson(item)`

and as a reference, the class i am trying to serialize into Json is:

```
public class Person{

    String name;
    boolean ownIt;
    Drawable image;
    String status;
    int backgroundColor;

    public Person(){}

    public Person(String n, Drawable d, String s, int b)
    {
        this.name= n;
        this.ownIt = false;
        this.image = d;
        this.status = s;
        this.backgroundColor = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.name.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: how big is your json object?

Comment: not very big, each one is 
list.add( new Person("Fred", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fred207),"sick", Color.rgb(89,168,65))) ;

Comment: And what exactly is PersonDescriptionPage?

Comment: it is an android activity that contains 
two textViews, One ImageView and one Switch but the code never reaches it.

Comment: shouldn't the `Person`s fields be public or have getters/setters?

Comment: I just tried changing it to public and it still froze.

Comment: Try making Person class implement the Serializable interface

Comment: that didn't work either

Comment: Are you able to test it without the `image` field in `Person`?

Comment: managed to solve it?

Comment: just fixed it, in my case the issue was because I had a `Context` object. Marking it as `transient` solved the problem. You should probably mark `image` as transient as @Android777 suggested

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a Singleton to do this. I think it is exactly freezing at the image (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fred207)).
I suggest this

```
  public class Person{

        //singleton
        private static ArrayList<Person> persons=null;

        String name;
        boolean ownIt;
        Drawable image;
        String status;
        int backgroundColor;

        //only getPerson creates objects
        private Person(){}

        private Person(String n, Drawable d, String s, int b)
        {
            this.name= n;
            this.ownIt = false;
            this.image = d;
            this.status = s;
            this.backgroundColor = b;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.name.toString();
        }


        public static Person addPerson()
        {
            if(persons==null)
            {
                persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

            }
            Person pers = new Person();
            persons.add(pers);
            return pers;
        }

        public static Person addPerson(String n, Drawable d, String s, int b)
        {
            if(persons==null)
            {
                persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

            }
            Person pers = new Person(n,d,s,b);
            persons.add(pers);
            return pers;
        }

        public static Person getPerson(int index)
        {
            if(persons==null)
                return null;
            if(index>(persons.size()-1))
                return null;
            return persons.get(index);
        }

        public static ArrayList<Person> getPersons()
        {
            return persons;
        }

    }
```

1. Add this way

   ```
   Person.addPerson("Fred", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fred207),"sick", Color.rgb(89,168,65)) ;
   ```
2. Pass the position instead of Person

   ```
   PersonDescriptionPage.putExtra("position", position);
   ```
3. Retrieve your item

   ```
   Person.getPerson(position);
   ```

Comment: it was the image that was messing up. i got around it by making it a bitmap byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Add the transient keyword to the declaration of image.
I think Gson has some sort of problem finding the class members of all objects used by Drawable. Specifically, I think Rect is the culprit?

Anyways, transient makes that field not included in the serialize/deserialization of Gson. (It skips that member)